# Headphone Input Missing 14.04

Tags: 14.04, sound, pulseaudio, headphones

So I run an dual-boot Alienware M14x with Windows 8.1 as my main OS and Ubutnu 14.04 as my secondary. I love Ubuntu and it's great to take a break from Windows, but one problem I've had with 14.04 since I installed it is that I can't use my headphone jack at all. Speakers are fine, mic port is in the input tab, but nothing for headphones. I have done constant research to find a way to fix it but I've found nothing. I would love to use Ubuntu on my laptop much more but the fact I can't put on a pair of headphones makes me boot up in Windows more than I like.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Alienware m14x with Windows 7, and I had the same problem. I'm not exactly sure how I fixed it, but I went through a bunch of different stuff to try to fix it (none of which actually worked individually, but may have contributed to my solution), then I uninstalled the SoundBlaster Recon 3Di system on Windows, and when I went back to ubuntu, the middle jack worked for my headphones (and is still working).

Comment: I would think it is worth keeping this answer for a couple of days; The answer does not much, technically - but I feel it hints strongly to "the mess is in the hardware"; which makes some sense, when a standard audio connection consists of 6 separate connectors, and this set can be configured in about 12 way...